# Cells vanishing and reappearing when scrolling a UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am having some odd behaviour with my UITableView. When I scroll up and down sometimes the bottom row will vanish and disappear again. Not sure why this is happening. Each of my UITableCells contains 4 buttons like so :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    int x,y;
    x=5;
    y=0;
    for(int i = (int)indexPath.row*4; i<(int)indexPath.row*4+4; i++) {


        //make sure we don't hit a blank in the array
        if(i<[self.buttons count]) {

            UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            button = self.buttons[i];
            button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2;
            button.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 70, 70)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
            x+=80;

        }


    }



    return cell;

}
```

Could this be because I have the same cell reuse identifier for each cell? Does it need to be unique?

Comment: Your loop is very unreliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button = self.buttons[i];
```

You allocate and initialize a button and then reassign the variable to entry i of a buttons array. Was this meant to be something else?

Also you are adding buttons to the cell content as a subview. Cells are reused when you scroll, so you could easily be adding more than 4 buttons to a given cell which will be causing you display issues. When you dequeue a cell it could already have 4 buttons in it.

Can you not just have 4 buttons in the cell prototype, saving you all this effort in the code.

Comment: You're right my implementation is a mess. I should be using a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

No, cell reuse identifier need to be **constant** for a tableView. However you should use is as a static variable.

Change to `static NSString *cellID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cellID",indexPath.row];` instead of 
`NSString *cellID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row];`

Also are you making any changes in `willDisplayCell` or `didEndDisplayingCell` delegate methods. If yes Plz post that code too.

Comment: sorry I edited my question, didn't mean to have the cellID string in there. What I am using now is "cell" as the reuse ID. This is what I set it to in the interface builder. It complies but the table behaves strangely, rows vanish and some things don't look drawn properly. I haven't made any changes to those delegate methods you mentioned . It's when I scroll that the problems begin.

Answer (score 0):

Re-write like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  if (cell.contentView.subviews.count == 0) {

    int x,y;
    x=5;
    y=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        button = self.buttons[i];
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2;
        button.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 70, 70)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
        x+=80;
      }
    }
  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

return cell;

    }
}
```